# Communicating continuously between python script and C app

Tags: python, c

I have a python script that interfaces with some network pool to read data from, that
is continuously 320 bits. This 320 bits should be forward to some C app, that continuously
reads these 320 bits from the python script and places them into an int array[8]. To be honest, I have no idea whether this is possible at all and would be thankful for a starting point for this issue.

I tried to incooperate some of your ideas, trying to send data via stdin from python to the C app:

test.exe:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int ch;
    /* read character by character from stdin */
    do {
    ch = fgetc(stdin);
    putchar(ch);
    } while (ch != EOF);


    return 0;
}
```

test.py:

```
def run(self):

    while True:           
        payload = 'some data'
        sys.stdout.write(payload)
        time.sleep(5)
```

Then I start this whole thing using a pipe: python test.py | test.exe

Unfortunately, there is no data that is received on the test.exe side, shouldn't this data ba available on stdin?

Comment: "*I would be thankful for a starting point for this issue*" - You could start here: http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/

Comment: Does the C program already exist? If not, you could write it as a Python extension. If not, you're going to have to modify it anyway. How much freedom do you have with the C program?

Comment: May I recommend [0mq](http://www.zeromq.org/)

Comment: Thanks guys, with the C program I have all freedom that I need, totaly under my control :)

Comment: you could add `sys.stdout.flush()` before sleep

Answer (score 6):

There are several possible ways.

You could start the C program from the python program using the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module. In that case you could write from the python program to the standard input of the C program. This is probably the easiest way.

```
import subprocess

network_data = 'data from the network goes here'
p = subprocess.Popen(['the_C_program', 'optional', 'arguments'], 
                     stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p.stdin.write(network_data)
```

N.B. if you want to send data multiple times, then you should *not* use `Popen.communicate()`.

Alternatively, you could use [socket](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html). But you would have to modifiy both programs to be able to do that.

**Edit**: J.F Sebatian's comment about using a pipe on the command line is very true, I forgot about that! But the abovementioned technique is still useful, because it is one less command to remember and especially if you want to have two-way communication between the python and C programs (in which case you have to add `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` to the `subprocess.Popen` invocation and then your python program can read from `p.stdout`).

Comment: the easiest way is just: `python script.py | c_program`

Answer (score 3):

Already mentioned:

1. sockets (be careful about framing)
2. message queues

New suggestions:

1. ctypes (package up the C code as a shared object and call into it
   from python with ctypes)
2. Cython/Pyrex (a Python-like language that allows you to pretty
   freely mix python and C data)
3. SWIG (an interlanguage interfacing system)

In truth, sockets and message queues are probably a safer way to go.  But they likely will also mean more code changes.