# Reading messages from can bus and display on raspberry pi webpage

Tags: raspberry-pi, webserver, can-bus

This is a theorical question. I have no code and I am not looking for that, just knowledge.

I have a raspberry pi with a webserver and a waveshare can-hat. It receives various messages from a dozen devices.

among those messages a few contains data (some informations are divided over multiple messages).

My idea is to receive the messages, restore complete informations and write one file each.

then an ajax call reads each file and displays each value in the webpage. Probably once every second.

Is it possible to do that? is there a better way?

the receiving script will be made in C.

thank you for helping and sharing your knowledge!

Comment: I don't know much about Rasp pi but writing incoming messages to files sounds strange. Unless this is some sort of low traffic sensor network? Otherwise, the real-time pace of the average CAN bus will be hard to keep up with for the file storage memory.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be a better practice if you create some kind of process (or some kind of kernel module or daemon for example) which read out the data from CAN and you use this process with Python and use some sort of Webserver-API to display the data via web.
You can find some ideas for IPC between a `C` and a `Python` application [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13072634/communicating-continuously-between-python-script-and-c-app).

So one simple solution would be to create a socket system with a `C` guest and a `Python` master. Your `Python` application is a [`flask`](https://www.fullstackpython.com/flask.html) application which waits for a connection of the `C` application (or vice versa) and the `C` application transmit all incomming data to your `Python` application.

This would be a more neat solution than writing and reading a file.